# Can't open .css file with Visual Studio Commuinity 2017

Tags: css, visual-studio

I'm doing Bob Tabors HTML5 & CSS3 course and in the course he only uses Editor and Internet Explorer. I thought that it would be a bit more convinient if I use Visual Studio to code. The problem, I can't open a .css file directly. I can open it in Visual Studio and it behaves like a normal .css file, but when i try to set the "Always open with" to the devenv.exe it says that the file can't be opened with that programm. .html, .cs and .js all work when I try to open them with the devenv.exe.

Comment: Is this really such a big problem? When you're working on a project, you already have VS opened so you can just find the file in the sidebar and open it there, no need to search for it in the file explorer. And it's faster this way, at least in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, it's not thta big of a problem right now. I still wonder why it doesn't work though. I mean, there has to be a reason.

Comment: VS would be a slow solution if you edit the files one by one -- it is a heavy IDE, not a text editor. Every time you start it you'd have to wait for it to load a toolset you will barely use. You'd be better off with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead, it is quite faster and better at handling web development

Comment: The only reason I see is you're assigning a wrong executable as "Always open with" . And I agree with @Ivaylo Slavov, VS takes forever to load and isn't practical for editing files one by one.

Comment: Well the devenv.exe works for everything else and is kinda the visualstudio.exe if you will. I don't know of any other .exe that would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the advice from @Ivaylo Slavov , I just decided to download Visual Studio Code. Seems to be a faster solution for editing .html and .css files.